When should I make my own Postgres extension
I've been reading some stuff about postgres extensions, and I've got some interested about writing my own extension in C to attend a demand from my company.
The scenario is:
We have a big and slow query that iterates through all the schemas verifying a specific datetime column from a specific table. A cron runs this query every 5 hours.
Does it make sense to write a extension that does same thing in C? Would it be a benefit or am I misunderstanding the concept of postgres extensions?

What problem should the extension solve? This job is not going to be faster just because it's an extension. So what are you doing to do differently? And why do you need an extension to do so? SELECT pg_sleep(10); always takes the same amount of time, with or without an extension.

Vote to reopen: the question can and has been answered "with facts and citations". The question might sound like it, but as demonstrated by the answer, it isn't very opinion-based, especially since OP describes a specific use case.

You have to distinguish these two things:

A PostgreSQL extension is an “installation package” in the database. If you create the extension, that will automatically create a number of database objects in the database (the members of the extension). These objects could be anything, and there is no relationship to C code.

A user-defined function in language C is a database function that calls a function in a shared library, which is dynamically linked into the server the first time you call the function in a database session.


It may make sense to package your C function into an extension, but those two things are in principle independent.
To figure out if your task would be faster in a C function, you have to figure out where the time is spent. If the time is spent performing sequential scans on tables, a C function won't help you. You'd need an index to speed that up. On the other hand, if most of your time is spent in PL/pgSQL function code that performs calculations or loops through query results, a C function can speed up processing considerably.
